# what aspect ratios does ffmpeg support?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

In the documentation ffmpeg has this:

```
`-aspect aspect'
Set aspect ratio (4:3, 16:9 or 1.3333, 1.7777).
```

Is this implying that it only supports those two aspect ratios or are those just examples for how to set the ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it means you can either supply it in the "X:Y" format or as a decimal.